# Delete an array line based on two conditions

Tags: perl

I have a 3 dimendional array like:

```
$a[0][0]=1;    $a[0][1]=2;    $a[0][2]=1;
$a[1][0]=1;    $a[1][1]=3;    $a[1][2]=-1;
$a[2][0]=2;    $a[2][1]=4;    $a[2][2]=1;
```

I would like to erase the line that has as the first two elements the values 1 and 3 (in this case the whole a[1][0 .. 2] elements. The output I would like to obtain is:

```
$a[0][0]=1;    $a[0][1]=2;    $a[0][2]=1;
$a[1][0]=2;    $a[1][1]=4;    $a[1][2]=1;
```

I am looking for a general solution for this problem. With one condition I would use the `grep` function, but I don't know how to do it with 2 conditions..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing as a 2D array in Perl. `@a` is just an array of references. So you're not trying to delete `$a[1][0 .. 2]`, but just `$a[1]`.

Yet you can't really delete from an array. Using [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html), you can shift all the elements around,

```
for my $i (reverse 0 .. $#a) {
   splice(@a, $i, 1) if $a[$i][0]==1 && $a[$i][1]==3;
}
```

But it's usually simpler and more efficient to remove the unwanted elements using [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) and assigning the rest back to the array.

```
@a = grep { !( $_->[0]==1 && $_->[1]==3 ) } @a;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Data::Dumper;
$a[0][0]=1;    $a[0][1]=2;    $a[0][2]=1;
$a[1][0]=1;    $a[1][1]=3;    $a[1][2]=-1;
$a[2][0]=2;    $a[2][1]=4;    $a[2][2]=1;


print Dumper(\@a);
@b=grep(!($_->[0]==1 && $_->[1]==3),@a);
print Dumper(\@b);
```